# Column name as a parameter to Spring Data JPA Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to inject an Entity property dynamically to `@Query`? My need is to implement a method like follows:

```
@Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.***columnName*** = ?2")
List<T> findAll(String ***columnName***, String value);
```

Any other simple ways of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using Spring Specification.

Your specification method will be similar to the following one:

```
public static Specification<Entity> byColumnNameAndValue(String columnName, String value) {
    return new Specification<Entity>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Entity> root,
                CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            return builder.equal(root.<String>get(columnName), value);
        }
    };
}
```

Please read a little about Specification, it's a great tool.

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

and

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specifications.html

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I used it and got the job done.!