# Ignite spring data custom sql query

Tags: java, spring-data, ignite

Im using ignite with spring data integration.
But I have a requirement to build a SQL query dynamically and execute on top of ignite. 
In the request I get the column name and the value.

Depending on that a query should be executed.

For an example 
Select * from extable where “columnName”=“value”

How to acheive this?

When using the `criteria api` or `queryDSl` we have to use 'if' Clause structure to map the column name search for a criteria.

How to avoid that and just provide column name and value as parameters 
something similar to the following?

```
      @Query("Select * from Account where ?=?")
      List<Account> find(String columnName, String value);
```

Comment: although the duplicated question is about HQL (which I cannot really guess by your question, as it was not mentioned), the same argument applies to other JPA implementation, and also SQL (OP was mentioning SQL, but it is obviously not SQL in his question)

Comment: Another related duplicate: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075385/column-name-as-a-parameter-to-spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: That seems legit. Thanks! my bad..

Comment: In addition to that you can't add `?` dynamically in the `@Query("Select * from Account where ?=?")` is a constant - so you can't add these ? on demand / dynamically. Preferred approach is to use Ignite SqlQuery abstraction to write custom query.