# Spring Data Jpa specification implementation of given problem

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I am having a table like

```
ColA        ColB
Name1       1
Name1       2
Name2       1
Name2       3
Name2       5
```

I want to fetch my result set as

```
ColA        ColB
Name1       1
Name2       1
```

How can we implement it in spring data JPA specification ?

Comment: Why does ColB mean in your expected output?

Comment: I think you have to describe your case more detailed. I mean, e.g tell us more about which values you want to pass to query to achive this result and other helpful information which we allow us to answer your question more precisely.

Comment: I need not pass any values into it. I just want to print min value of ColB corresponding to a Name. Ex: Name1 has a min value of 1, Name2 has a min value of 1

Comment: yes min function in available in Specification

Comment: It's impossible in Spring Data JPA using Specification to achieve what you want because Specification affects only the WHERE clause of the SQL statement whereas you need SQL GROUB BY and MIN functionality.

Comment: @Robert Niestroj : No, its possible with Spring Data JPA  using Specification. We can also modify select using Specification Ex:-query.select(cb.min(root.get(column.getName())));

Comment: Groupby option availabale in specification "query.groupBy(cb)"

Comment: javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<User> check this interface you will find functions and clauses

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in your repository interface. I think it should work.

```
    @Async
   @Query(value = "select * " +
                " from TableA ta " +
                "where ta.colb = :colb",nativeQuery=true)
    List<T> findByColA(@Param("colb") String colb);
```

or

with specification

Create Specification Object:

***Criteria functions(SUM, MAX or MIN) for Specification***:

`javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T>` Check this interface to find more information.

```
    final class UserSpecifications {

        private UserSpecifications() {}

        static Specification<User> findData(String colb, String columnName) {
                  return new Specification<User>() {
                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root,                                 
                                    CriteriaQuery<?> query, 
                                    CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                     root = query.from(User.class);
                     Predicate colbp = cb.equal(root.get(columnName), colb);
                     Expression<String> groupByExp = root.get(columnname).as(String.class);
                     query.where(colbp);
                     query.select(cb.min(root.get(column.getName())));
                     query.groupBy(groupByExp);                         
                }
            }
       }
    }

    Specification<User> spec = UserSpecifications.findData("1", "columnName");

    List<User> allUsers = repository.findAll(spec);
```

Tutorial :[Spring data Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)

specification example: [Spring Data specification](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-four-jpa-criteria-queries/)

Spring Specification example:[Spring Specification How-to](https://leaks.wanari.com/2018/01/23/awesome-spring-specification/)

Stackoverflow ref: [Spring Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075385/column-name-as-a-parameter-to-spring-data-jpa-query)

Comment: I want to use with Specification. So that i can pass findAll(specification)

Comment: yes u can also do it with specification List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);

Comment: My doubt is how to construct that Specification Object.

Comment: I sent the link, there you find example

Comment: UserSpecification spec1 = 
      new UserSpecification(new SearchCriteria("age", ">", "25"));
    UserSpecification spec2 = 
      new UserSpecification(new SearchCriteria("lastName", ":", "doe"));
 
    List<User> results = 
      repository.findAll(Specifications.where(spec1).and(spec2));

Comment: Create a new Specification<T> object. I hope this info helps you

Comment: Follow this Example :   https://leaks.wanari.com/2018/01/23/awesome-spring-specification/

Comment: My doubt is to how to implement Max and min functions and spring data JPA. Because i dont think so it is easy to construct Specification object for my problem. Can some clearly construct a specification object for my proble

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934549/spring-specification-with-sum-function example for sum function, probably it works for max and min functions also. Just try it. Hopefully it will work

Comment: query.select(criteriaBuilder.min(root.get(column.getName()))); you have to include this statement in your specification object

Comment: criteria functions(sum,max or min) available in spring specification.

Comment: This answer should have been the accepted answer. It is well articulated with great links. @NarayanYerrabachu answer and comments just helped me out greatly on a complex query we are working on with many joins and special criteria.